# Is there a complete summarized list of attacks on elliptic curve cryptography?

Tags: elliptic-curves, resources

Is there a complete summarized list of attacks on elliptic curve cryptography? In RSA, there is [https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf), so I was wondering if there is such a list somewhere. I have found many online resources for different attacks, but I haven't found a complete list like the one on RSA. Does a complete list exist? And if so could you please share it?

Comment: https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/